# DatePicker for WindowBuilder?

Tags: java, datepicker, windowbuilder

I am using WindowBuilder (Eclipse Juno 4.2) to create GUI for my project. In that GUI I need to use date picker. I searched online for some date pickers and found out some library that will do work but for some reason I can't implemet it in WindowBuilder. Is there any Date picker that will work (that can be added as a Window Builder component) with WindowBuilder. Regards.

Comment: http://jcalendarbutton.sourceforge.net/ worked for me 3 years ago. Dont remember if i integrated it in WB or called manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend [jCalendar](http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/) for your date picker widget.

Just right-click on the swing palette, then choose Palette Manager and from there you can add the jCalendar Jar files.

Answer (score 0):

For SWT there is an internal date picker but also a myriad of widgets in the Eclipse Nebula project.